# Create Timesequence in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, time-series

I have an excel file where my starting timestamp is 00:00:00.002. I would like to create a time sequence of 2 ms in the following columns like 00:00:00.004,00:00:00.006 and so on. 
I have tried dragging the cells but after 1000 ms it should change the seconds like 00:00:00.998,00:00:01.000. How do i do that in excel.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format A1 as `hh:mm:ss.000_)` then put in this formula and drag right.

```
=COLUMN(A:A)*TIME(0,0,2)/1000
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried several formulas. But before that when i format the cells as hh:mm:ss.000 or as you specified excel throws an error saying "Microsoft excel cannot use the number format you typed"

Comment: Put the start time in A1 then use `=A1+COLUMN(A:A)*TIME(0,0,2)/1000`